# How to create a new object instead of assigning a reference to the existing object in `Vue3 Option Api`

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

```
props:{
    variants:{
        type: Array,
        default: []
    }
    options:{
        type: Array,
        default: []
    },
},
data(){
    return{
        item:{
            quantity: 1,
            options: this.options,
        },
    }
},
```

I have a problem with this code: When i change `item.options` value also `options` get changed because as i understand, i am just assigning a reference to `options`.

How to create a new object for `item.options` instead of assigning a reference to the existing object in `Vue3 Option Api`.

I tried `{...this.options}` but it didnt work.

Comment: options: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.options))  Look additional at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's an array of primitives, shallow cloning is enough to achieve the desired result:

```
item:{
    quantity: 1,
    options: [...this.options],
}
```

Otherwise, you will need to perform deep cloning for which there are multiple ways to achieve it, you can search for it however using `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({}))` isn't recommended.

Comment: Yep, creating a deep clone was the solution that worked for me, since `options` contains nested objects.
I used `lodash` lib to do this.

Comment: but why `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({}))` isn't recommended?

Comment: you can refer this article: https://medium.com/@pmzubar/why-json-parse-json-stringify-is-a-bad-practice-to-clone-an-object-in-javascript-b28ac5e36521

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```
data(){
    return{
        item:{
            quantity: 1,
            options: Object.assign({}, this.options),
        },
    }
},
```

I would change the name of the prop to `optionsProp` for better readability!

Answer (score 0):

You should use Array `[]` brackets instead of object brackets `{}`

```
options: [...this.options]
```

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue

const Comp = {
  props: {
      options: {
          type: Array,
          default: []
      }
  },
  data() {
      return {
          item: {
              options: [...this.options],
          }
      }
  },
  methods: {
    addOption() {
      this.item.options.push('New Option')
    }
  },
  template: `<div>options: {{options}},<br/>item.options: {{item.options}}<br/>
  <button @click="addOption()">addOption</button>
  </div>
  `
}

const App = {
  components: {
    Comp
  },
  setup() {
    const options = ref(['One','Two']);
    return {
      options
    }
  }
}

const app = createApp(App)
app.mount('#app')
```

```css
#app { line-height: 1.75; }
[v-cloak] { display: none; }
```

```html
<div id="app" v-cloak>
  <comp :options="options"></comp>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```